# HTTPS not valid with Google Search Console (prevents indexing)

Tags: google-search-console, https, google-index

I want to index in Google a website that I have coded, but it is not working because an error:

> HTTPS not valid, and that should prevent indexing.

However, I have a valid SSL certificate. Here is the screenshot of the Google Search Console:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The site works for me in Firefox, Chrome, and Curl.  [SSL Labs gives a "B" score with no major problems](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yogi-dream.fr)  I'm not seeing what Google might be complaining about.

Comment: And there is even DNSSEC on the domain which is good!

Comment: Can you do a "live" test in Google Search Console's URL inspection tool?  Maybe it is complaining about something it fetched a while ago before you made changes.

Comment: I don’t know how to say more about my problem. Yes, I saw that everything was good in the navigator. I did a live test, and everything is ok. I really don’t understand what is going on with the Google Search Console.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an **untrusted or invalid certificate**.

I get an *alternative name mismatch* error for *cluster030.hosting.ovh.net*

Here's the output, expand on certificate 2, and you'll see the diagnostic:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yogi%2ddream.fr&s=2001%3a41d0%3a301%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a30